# In Zkoss selected checkbox is setDisabled(true) but i want visibility of checkbox and tick remain same

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, zk

```
for(int i=0;i<list_id.size();i++)
            {
                count++;
                Listitem l1=new Listitem();
                org.zkoss.zul.Checkbox ccc=new org.zkoss.zul.Checkbox();
                l1.setParent(signlist);
                Listcell c1=new Listcell();
                Listcell c2=new Listcell();
                Listcell c3=new Listcell();
                c1.setParent(l1);
                c2.setParent(l1);
                c3.setParent(l1);
                c2.setLabel(""+count);
                c3.setLabel(getSignId(list_id.get(i),temp)); 
                ccc.setParent(c1);              
                ccc.setId(list_id.get(i)+":"+i+group_id);
                InputStream in =rs.getAsciiStream(2);
                StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
                IOUtils.copy(in, w);
                mapped_sign = w.toString();
                if(mapped_sign.contains("|"))
                {
                    list_Name=mapped_sign.split("\\|");
                    for(int k=0;k<list_Name.length;k++)
                    {
                        list_id_Check.add(list_Name[k]);
                    }
                    if(list_id_Check.contains(list_id.get(i)))
                    {
                        ccc.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if(list_id.get(i).equals(mapped_sign))
                    {
                        ccc.setChecked(true);
                    }
                }
                ccc.setDisabled(true);

            c3.setId(list_id.get(i)+":"+group_id);  
            }
```

when i apply setDisabled(true) then selected and unslected checkbox visibility goes to fade. i just want after applying setDisabled the visibility of checkbox and tick still remain same.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me: Do you want the visibility of the checkbox to be modified according to its checked state, or do you want to the checkboxes to have the same style independently of the disabled state? The first would mean, that an unchecked checkbox would not be visible to the user. The second would mean, that the user cannot distinguish between disabled and enabled checkboxes by sight.

Comment: i want to the checkboxs to have the same style when disabled state but know one can tick or untick on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no ZK-specific way to do that.
Nevertheless, you can use ordinary CSS (and maybe a custom checkbox sprite) to style your own checkboxes.

Here is an [example](http://zkfiddle.org/sample/5jfprs/1-SO36614604) (CSS taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Forms/Advanced_styling_for_HTML_forms)

```
<zk>
  <window border="normal" title="hello">
    <style>
        :root input[type=checkbox] {
          /* original check box are push outside the viexport */
          position: absolute;
          left: -1000em;
        }

        :root input[type=checkbox] + label:before {
          content: "";
          display: inline-block;
          width  : 16px;
          height : 16px;
          margin : 0 .5em 0 0;
          background: url("https://developer.mozilla.org/files/4173/checkbox-sprite.png") no-repeat 0 0;

        /* The following is used to adjust the position of 
           the check boxes on the text baseline */

          vertical-align: bottom;
          position: relative;
          bottom: 2px;
        }

        :root input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
          background-position: 0 -16px;
        }



    </style>
    <vlayout>
          <checkbox id='chk1' label='enabled' />
          <checkbox id='chk2' label='disabled unchecked' disabled='true' />
          <checkbox id='chk3' label='disabled checked' checked='true' disabled='true' />
    </vlayout>

  </window>
</zk>
```

Of course, you should not link to mozilla's sprite but supply your own.

Here is a SO answer providing further links and examples: [How to style checkbox using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: Thanks @flo this is helpfull.